# JBPM vs AWS SWF

Tags: amazon-web-services, jbpm, business-process-management, amazon-swf

I am new to BPM tools and I have a choice to choose between JBPM and AWS SWF for my Java application workflow. Don't have enough deadline to work on both and than choose. My other applications will be hosted on AWS only and if I use JBPM and that will also be hosted on AWS.

So I need to choose between the above mentioned on the base of complexity in use, cost, reliability, flexibility and maintenance and the possible disadvantages involved.

You are free to add on something which I am missing. You can also provide some comparison blogs or URLs which I can refer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JBPM, but I can tell you that Amazon SWF is not a traditional BPM solution. It is for writing robust batch like processes that can be distributed and parallelized over many machines. While you can use it for creating business processes it operates at a lower level than a typical BPM product.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still wondering on this ....

Choice between SWF vs jBPM -  really depends on your application use case. 
That said, here's a quick overview in layman terms

**Complexity** - jBPM is more complex and robust than SWF

**Reliability** - Application reliability is more based on how you write your application and has less to do with which framework you choose. So, this has no bearing on what you choose.

**Cost** - Well, similar to reliability, very subjective. jBPM is open source workflow engine but once you build your application you would have to run into AWS and that cost depends on how many instances, how much throughput, etc, etc.

**Maintenance** - I think AWS SWF would be easier to maintain only because its a simpler framework with limited functionality.

I think you start with **your application requirements** and from there, you understand what kind of capabilities you need and then decide.

For example, if you don't need robust workflow and business process in your application, then you can go with AWS SWF.

Also, your preferred **programming language** should be considered as well - Java (for jBPM) vs Java, Php, Ruby, .NET,etc (for SWF).